# ExtJs - Panel grid data not visible even when it is loaded by the store

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I'm using a panel grid to display some data. The grid has only one column hence the model has only one field.

The model definition is as follows:

```
Ext.define('someModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'name', type: 'auto'},
    ]
});
```

The store proxy is as follows:

```
proxy: {
    type        : 'direct',
    directFn    : 'someFunction',
    extraParams: {
        controller: ''
    },
    reader      : {
        type            : 'json',
        root            : 'result'
    }
}
```

The proxy returns me the data as a JSON object and I can see it in the console. 
Here is the format:

```
{
    "result": {
        "somekey": "somevalue",
        "values": {
            "abc": "xyz",
            "pqr": "mno"
        },
        "arrays": [
            "value"
        ],
        "onemorekey": "value"
    },
    "id": 0001
}
```

I want to parse this data and use the `arrays` part of it as the data to my grid. It can contain more than one values. I'm not able to see or set any data from this JSON to my grid. Can someone tell me how to do it?

Comment: Your model is wrong, it has to have the data structure. And why is your JSON so complicated if you want to show only the arrays?

Comment: It's coded by someone else! I'm just fixing the UI side. Besides, it works, I turned off autoload.